# What's this grey triangle arrow means in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version-control, ide

[image: IntelliJ editor image]

**What is this icon?**

Some codes are "hidden" because of this icon, when I click it, the IDE pops up the code snippet that's supposed to be there before, since codes disappeared, I can't reference it from other files either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using a version control system (such as [Git](https://git-scm.com/)) in the project you are working on with the IDE, you will see these marks on the files (See sample images below).

#### File content

- Grey triangles: deleted content
- Blue rectangles: changed content
- Green rectangles: added new content

[image: Example image that shows the CVS content changes in a file]

These are seen when the changes are not yet committed. Once all the changes are committed the marks are gone.

If you click on those marks you will see the content that was there before the change took place.

#### Files

The same principle is applied for files (see below images)

- Green: new file
- Blue: modified file
- Grey: deleted file

While working you see the files like this (deleted ones are omitted):

[image: Example image that shows the CVS file structure changes]

And, by the time you're committing changes you will see them like this (you see all files changed):

[image: Example image that shows the CVS file structure changes when committing the changes]

---

[See official doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html#d859473e346) for more info.