# Maven project doesn't open correct in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have maven spring boot project generated in spring initializer. Every time when I switch to this project in IntelliJ Idea project doesn't open correct. It means every java classes have red J icon until I click with right mouse button on project and go into `Run Maven > Reimport`

[image]

When I switch to another projects which are maven spring boot projects as well, projects are open correctly. I have problem only with this one. Do you have idea how to fix it without reimport every time when I open project?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us with the code? Impossible to say with this info. The green color means "new element" in the VCS. See this  for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45154141/5640649

Comment: @lealceldeiro I know that color is related with git. I have no problem with that. Problem is with that red icons of source files

Comment: @DenisStephanov please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891. See what errors are logged when the project is imported. If there is `.idea` directory, delete it and reimport.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried remove .idea folder :/ also I check problems in project configuration and there isn't anyone. I just created new spring project and switch to another which already works. Then I switch back and project isn't imported well and I have to do manually.

Comment: @DenisStephanov any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Can you share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

you have to `Enable Auto import` Maven.. In the right bottom corner of IntelliJ , there is a **Event Log** tab. when you click it It might be show you the option `Enable Auto Import`. Or manually you have to enable Auto import by go to the settings. Then every time IntelliJ automatically import the Project as Maven.